# Complex structure acting on two-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, complex-geometry

$\quad$
Let $J$ be an almost complex structure on a real $2n$-dimensional differentiable manifold $M$.
Then $J$ can be thought of as a $(^1{}_1)$-tensor such that, if a vector $X\in \Gamma(TM)$ decomposes into holomorphic and anti-holomorphic parts as $X^{(1,0)}$ and $X^{(0,1)}$,
\begin{align}
J(X) = iX^{(1,0)} - iX^{(0,1)}
\,.
\end{align}
Now, I am wondering if we can build a $(_2{}^2)$-tensor $K$ such that, for a two-form $F\in\Gamma(\wedge^2(T^*M))$,
\begin{align}
F = F^{(2,0)} + F^{(1,1)} + F^{(0,2)}
\quad\implies\quad
K(F) = i F^{(2,0)} + 0 F^{(1,1)} + (-i) F^{(0,2)} = iF^{(2,0)} -iF^{(0,2)}
\,,
\end{align}
where $F^{(2,0)}$, $F^{(1,1)}$, and $F^{(0,2)}$ are the $(2,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,2)$ parts of $F$, respectively.
That is, $K$ has eigenvalues $+i$, $0$, and $-i$ for those three subspaces.
How can I express $K$ in terms of $J$?
I am afraid that this may be a silly question that has a very simple answer, but I am not being able to find one. I have tried something like $J^\top\otimes J^\top$, where $J^\top$ is a $(_1{}^1)$-tensor version of $J$,
\begin{align}
A = A^{(1,0)} + A^{(0,1)}\in\Gamma(T^*M) \quad\implies\quad
J(A) = iA^{(1,0)} - iA^{(0,1)}
\,.
\end{align}
But this gives eigenvalues $-1$, $1$, and $-1$, not $+i$, $0$, and $-i$.

$\quad$
The context of this question is self-dual and anti-self-dual two-forms in a $(3,1)$-signature pseudo-Riemannian manifold and their association with holomorphy/anti-holomorphy.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> At a quick skim, the problem appears to be the wish to express $K$ in terms of $J$. Is that necessary for the intended purposes?

Comment: Thank you Andrew D. Hwang! It does not "have" to, and I could have just defined $K$ like that. But, I'm wondering if I could implement things from a minimal set of "basic" elements.

Comment: Because $J$ multiplies $dz$ and its conjugate by $-i$ or $i$, $J$ has eigenvalues $\pm1$ on $2$-forms, as you've found. (More precisely, $J$ acts with eigenvalues $\pm i$ on the _complexified_ tangent bundle, so the induced complex structure also has eigenvalues $\pm i$ on the complexified cotangent bundle and the induced operator on $2$-forms is multiplication by $\pm1$ on the graded pieces. If it matters, the eigenvalue on the $(1,1)$ piece is $1$.) [...]

Comment: Also if it matters, $J$ has no eigenvectors on the real bundle, even if the dimension is even; to get eigenvectors of $J$ we need to construct formal complex linear combinations of real tangent vectors, i.e., we need to complexify the tangent bundle. The holomorphic tangent bundle is the complex subbundle of the complexification on which $J$ acts by multiplication by $i$.